# Dual expander bleed cycle

Tags: rockets, engines

Would dual expander bleed cycle be a good idea?
The lox will pass through the nozzle and drive the lox pump
And the fuel will also pass through the nozzle to drive the fuel pump

Both will be expander bleed cycles  the fuel could be methane or propane

Comment: yes. https://blogs.nasa.gov/J2X/2014/03/24/inside-the-leo-doghouse-the-art-of-expander-cycle-engines/